# Using CGPoints in an NSArray

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsarray, cgpoint

I have been trying to create an array stating the location of a UIImageView in an app I've been working on.  What I am trying to do is by using an array I can store the location of my "player" image by using its x,y and z coordinates.  The script I am trying to accomplish would look like

```
NSArray *location[3];
-(IBAction)startup;{
[location addObject: player.center.x];
[location addObject: player.center.y];
[location addObject: playerheight];
}
```

So I will be able to access this array to move my "player" on the screen in "3-dimensions", but I don't know how to convert the CGpoint values to NSValues so they can be used in the array, is there a simple way to do this inside of the array?

Answer (score 11):

To convert floating point values to objects, use NSNumber.  NSValue has wrappers for geometric types like CGPoint.  Either would work for you.

```
[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:player.center];

[NSNumber numberWithFloat:player.center.x];
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:player.center.y];
```

Answer (score 7):

To addition for the first answer.
When you'll need to read `CGPoint` back from your array, you can use something like that:

```
CGPoint point = [(NSValue *)[pointsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that there's no `addObject` method for `NSArray` (you can't add objects to an NSArray after its been created); you want `NSMutableArray`.

Instead of:

```
NSArray *location[3];
```

you probably want something more like:

```
NSMutableArray *location = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an NSArray?  Why not use an array of structs?

```
typedef struct {
    CGPoint location;
    CGFloat height;
} PlayerLocation;

PlayerLocation players[3];

players[0].location = player.center;
players[0].height   = playerheight;
```

Or depending on your design it may make more sense to declare an objective-C class that contains the x,y,z coordinates as ivars and store those objects into an NSArray.

```
@interface PlayerLocation : NSObject {
  CGPoint location;
  CGFloat height;
}
@end
```